# Are FHIR code systems available in OMOP from Athena?

Tags: hl7-fhir, ohdsi-omop

FHIR seems to have implemented their own coding systems.  For example, this was found in a Synthea patient:

```
          "valueCoding": {
            "code": "2106-3",
            "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
            "display": "White"
          }
```

Which seems to be from:
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/us/core/CodeSystem-cdcrec.html

I'm not seeing anything on the Athena terminology download page for this (login required).
https://athena.ohdsi.org/vocabulary/list

The code '2106-3' does appear in the standard download of terminology from Athena but as a LOINC code for a Choriogonadotropin test (so, not the same thing).

Are these FHIR terminologies available for OMOP in Athena (or elsewhere)?

Is there a place to download all of these FHIR terminologies in csv (or other bulk uploadable format)?

Answer (score 1):

The FHIR terminologies can be downloaded as XML or JSON.  Some have hierarchy and relationships, so flat CSV files are harder, though I believe there's a proposal to add that to FHIR IG publication tooling in the future.  Note that FHIR is a data exchange standard and the terminologies themselves are defined in a variety of places - some on http://terminology.hl7.org, some in the core FHIR specification and some in different FHIR implementation guides (which can be defined by anyone).  As such, there won't be a single place to download content, though there are registries you can use to search and download large sets of them.